# Get LAN client machine name in servlet based web application

Tags: servlets, client-side, lan, computer-name

I have spring MVC application, that runs in LAN. In there client machines IP addresses are changing time to time. Therefore I want to get client machines names(Their machine name is fixed ),because I want to get client machine's details without creating log in.

Is that possible to get client machine's name?? if it's possible how??
Or is there any other way to get that user details

Edit:
codes I have tried so far

In HttpServlet

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException { 
    String hostname = request.getRemoteUser(); //this gives null
    String hostname = request.getRemoteHost(); //This gives host machine name
}
```

Edit: reply to @Eugeny Loy
In web.xml

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>jcifs.smb.client.username</param-name>
    <param-value>username</param-value>

</init-param>
```

In serverlet class

```
String username = config.getInitParameter("username");//This gives client IP address
```

Comment: Can you show us the codes you have tried so far?

Comment: while asking questions show the codes as well.It will attract more users to answer.

Comment: when you are using System.out.println() then it will be printed in the console of the server machine

Comment: @Neha have you managed to solve this issue? Was my answer helpful? Need some clarification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the way to get client machine's name.

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException { 

    Logger.getLogger(this.getClass()).warning("Inside Confirm Servlet");  
    response.setContentType("text/html");

    String hostname = request.getRemoteHost(); // hostname
    System.out.println("hostname"+hostname);

    String computerName = null;
    String remoteAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();
    System.out.println("remoteAddress: " + remoteAddress);
    try {
        InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName(remoteAddress);
        System.out.println("inetAddress: " + inetAddress);
        computerName = inetAddress.getHostName();

        System.out.println("computerName: " + computerName);


        if (computerName.equalsIgnoreCase("localhost")) {
            computerName = java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost().getCanonicalHostName();
        } 
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {

        }

    System.out.println("computerName: " + computerName);
}
```

Comment: its not for get computer name! you just get the ip address and if so many pc connected into webapplication , result will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

> Is that possible to get client machine's name??

You're probably referring to NetBIOS name here. If that's the case - you should use some library that implements NetBIOS/SMB/CIFS in java to do this.

> if it's possible how??

Have a look on [JCIFS](http://jcifs.samba.org/). I won't give you the exact code snippet but this is the direction you should move to solve this.

> Or is there any other way to get that user details

As far as I understand your problem, what you need is a way to identify host and you cannot rely on IP address for that.

If that's the case one of the other options would be using MAC address, but you'll probably wont be able to do this with pure java since this is more low-level protocol java normally deals with, so it will probably be less portable. [This tutorial](http://www.gitspot.com/2012/02/java-code-to-get-mac-address-from.html) might help.

**UPDATE**

I come across NetBIOS/SMB/CIFS stack but I haven't worked with it *in Java and JCIFS*. That's why I won't give you specific code piece that will solve your issue but rather direction where you should look.

Check out [NbtAddress](http://stderr.org/doc/libjcifs-java-doc/api/jcifs/netbios/NbtAddress.html#getAllByAddress%28String%29) class docs. Seems to be what you are looking for. Also check out the [examples](http://jcifs.samba.org/src/examples/) to get the idea how it can be used.

Comment: sorry for the delay.I tried as you said and i edited my quetion with including that code. I tried it by using my machine as a server and and another machine as a client. But I got IP address of the other machine(not the user name).can you suggest a way to get that user name.