# how to capture users Machine Name from the http request?

Tags: javascript, java, single-sign-on, client-side

I am trying to implement session kill feature for my application.
I need to show user all the devices from which he has logged in.
But I am not able to get the users machine name from http request.

I have tried this:
[Another similar question in stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20492186/get-client-machine-name-in-lan)
But it gives user's machine name only if it is explicitly specified in hosts file and is the first entry there.

Google has implemented the similar feature
[google's implementation to review devices/sessions](https://security.google.com/settings/security/activity)

It shows the user's machine name
[image]

My machine name CITRUSPN135 is shown here.

How can I implement the similar feature for my application?
I am open for implementations both at front end or server side.

Comment: can not do, and even if you could do, if it passed through a proxy or gateway it would not be accurate

Comment: How google is doing it?

Comment: Maybe there are using some ajax code to send this information, but I do not think it would be from http request per se.

Comment: Then there must be some way to capture the device name from front end?

Comment: Please have look over this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9399767/2900034).

Comment: Google get this information with setup third-party apps into your phone or windows! like gmail app or chrome.

Answer (score 0):

server side code is there 
String browserType = request.getHeader("User-Agent");
it contains all the information